# Convert date by setting seconds and minutes to zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date in Excel like this:

`2017-08-24 08:04:42.560`

I need to convert it to this format:

`2017-08-24 00:00:00.000`

Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following in cell **B1**

```
=INT(A1)
```

[image]

Comment: @Rafael  If it does not work, then the data in **A1** is ***Text*** ......................a different formula must be used.................

Comment: You can make Excel change Date-as-text to an actual date by adding 0: `=Int(A1+0)`

Answer (score 2):

The following formulae work irrespective of the type of the original date (*Text* or *DateTime*).

**Formula 1** - (if the converted date is required to be of type *Text*)

```
=TEXT(INT(VALUE(A1)),"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000")
```

[image]

**Formula 2** - (if the converted date is required to be a proper *DateTime*)

```
=INT(VALUE(A1))
```

[image]

Remember to use the Custom value `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000` for the Number Format of the cell containing this second formula in order for the date to be displayed correctly.